# Translate Maple code into Mathematica

Tags: maple

I am trying to translate Maple code into *Mathematica*.

Here is my code:

[image: code]

Can anyone help me to obtain a translation?

I especially want to know the *Mathematica* equivalent of Maple's `_EnvAllSolutions`.

---

I would like to determine the equilibrium positions which are the solution of the trigonometric equation given

Comment: Hi. And how is your translation going?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This will likely influence what the code should look like in Mathematica. I'm not familiar with Maple, but even if I were I'm not sure your goal would be obvious to me.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them unreadable. Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code as text that can be copied and pasted in a _Mathematica_ notebook. Without such, no one will be able to reproduce your problem, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that identifiers in Mathematica cannot contain underscores (`_`), since the underscore is used for patterns.  I'm also using the character `θ` instead of `theta`, which you can enter with <kbd>ESC</kbd>`th`<kbd>ESC</kbd> or `\[Theta]`.

```
eq5 = -1/2 m g Cos[θ] l == 0;
```

Maple's `solve` seems to work the same way as `Solve` from what I see in your question.

```
sol = Solve[eq5, θ]
(* {{θ -> ConditionalExpression[-(π/2) + 2π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]},
    {θ -> ConditionalExpression[π/2 + 2π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}} *)
```

It returns a list of substitution rules.  We can apply those rules with `ReplaceAll`, or rather its infix form `/.`:

```
θ /. sol /. {C[1] -> 0}
(* {-(π/2), π/2} *)
```

I also used another substitution to replace the constant `C[1]` with `0`.  If you wanted to enumerate more solutions, you could replace with a `Range` instead.